# Sum of i.i.d. binomial distributed variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

This might be a stupid question, but somehow can't get my head over this problem.

I want to to compute the probability that

$P\left(\frac{X_1}{18}+\frac{X_2}{9}+\frac{X_3}{6} = \frac{1}{2}\right)$,

where $X_i$ i.i.d.~ $Bin(3, p)$.

I know that the sum of binomials is again a binomial. However, we have different constants before each variable, so we cannot write it in a form $P(X_1 + X_2 + X_3 = \dots)$.

Can anyone help my how I'd work out this probability?

Answer (score 1):

There are only $4^2 = 16$ possible outcomes for $(X_1, X_2)$, and given values for $X_1$ and $X_2$ you can compute what $X_3$ has to be for $X_1/18 + X_2/9 + X_3/6 = 1/2$.
It's not too hard to enumerate all possibilities.